# Blazor Wpf Hybrid throws error due to routing when running in .NET 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, .net-8.0

I'm converting my Blazor Wpf Hybrid Server side app from .NET 7 to .NET 8 and facing error when I'm launching the app. App is launching fine when I remove the Routing.

Anything else I am supposed to configure to overcome this error in .NET 8

Error:

InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'ScrollToLocationHash' on type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.Router'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing.IScrollToLocationHash'.